# :active pseudo-class doesn't work in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, pseudo-class

`:active` pseudo-class works perfectly in mobile Safari and stock Android browser, but fails in Chrome on Android. (Tested on Nexus 4 Chrome, iPhone 4S Safari, Galaxy SII Browser.)

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show the actual code (HTML and CSS) you're using? Perhaps provide a sample site we can look at to see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :active pseduo works on Chrome for Android, but only after a long press (and cancel of the dialog), it doesn't work for any other element as far as I can tell.  It looks like a bug, and I have just [raised it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173976) with the team.

Example: [http://jsbin.com/itikox/2](http://jsbin.com/itikox/2#)